# calculate error neural network

Tags: neural-network

Recently I have been implementing neural networks for my research. While trying to design the error of the neural network, I got confused on several things because I found several ways to compute mean square error:

1. global error= sigma of ((Tik-Yik)^2 )
   where i= number of output neuron and k= number of training data
   RMS= sqrt(global error/i+k)
2. global error= sigma of ((Tik-Yik)^2 )
   where i= number of output neuron and k= number of training data
   mean error= sigma of((Tik-mean(Tik))^2)
   where i=number of output neuron and k=number of trainingdata
   RMS=global error/mean error

I got confused about those two, can somebody explain to me which one is the right one? Or both  are true?

Comment: You may want to link to the source of these equations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are the equations you're referring to :

[image]

If so, the RMS<sub>1</sub>  value looks like a valid RMS expression, while RMS<sub>2</sub> is simply a fractional expression, not an RMS expression at all.

Just one thing though: it looks like your RMS<sub>1</sub> also contains an error/typo: the denominator of the contents of your sqrt() should be simply "k", not "i+k". I think you should simply divide by the training set size, and not include the neuron count in there.

It would be useful if you also cited your references for these equations.